# jquery one() doesnot working correctly in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to translate a `p` tag and after the transition ends, increase font size by 6 by Jquery one() function but it works 2 times in the google-chrome

css

```
p {

    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: transform 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: transform 1s;
}
```

full sample at http://jsfiddle.net/7bdkr1yd/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because Chrome will fire on both the`webkitTransitionEnd` and `transitionend` events as mentioned by the previous answer. However, removing `webkitTransitionEnd` will result in the callback not firing in Safari. To have it work consistently across all browsers, you can simply use a boolean check within the callback function.

```
var fired = false;
$( "p" ).one( "webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend", function( event ) {
    if ( !fired ) {
        fired = true;
        // do your stuff here
    }
});
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) and working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7bdkr1yd/2/)

Answer (score 1):

That is because two event `webkitTransitionEnd` and `transitionend` are attached in chrome.To resolve this, you can check for class say `doneamnimation` added before running the animation. if not, then do the animation and add class to element:

```
$("p").one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend", function(event ){
   if($(this).is('.doneamnimation'))
    $(this).addClass('doneamnimation').animate({fontSize: "+=6px"});
});
```

### Demo